# how to make my 1st array size to be the same as my 2nd array?

Tags: python

I am having a problem where I want to make my first array to be the same size of my 2nd array. Here is my code:

```
print("1ST INPUT")
num_array = list()
num = int(input("Enter how many elements you want: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    element = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array.append(element)

    print("2nd input")
    num_array2 = list()
    for i in range(0, num): #I want to make the same size of element from the first one.
        element1 = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
        num_array2.append(element1)
```

For example, I inputted 5 in size of array in my first input. I want to make my array size in 2nd input to be 5.

Comment: Is the indentation for the second loop intetional? Why are you doing it inside the first loop? Should it be outside?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dedent the second for-loop:

```py
print("1ST INPUT")
num_array = list()
num = int(input("Enter how many elements you want: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    element = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array.append(element)

print("2nd input")
num_array2 = list()
for i in range(0, num): #I want to make the same size of element from the first one.
    element1 = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array2.append(element1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("1ST INPUT")
num_array = list()
num = int(input("Enter how many elements you want: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    element = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array.append(element)

print("2nd input")
num_array2 = list()
for i in range(0, len(num_array)):  # I want to make the same size of element from the first one.
    element1 = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array2.append(element1)
```

Comment: That is the same as the other answer

Comment: yeah it's matter of seconds almost 30 sec later due to my poor connection :(

Answer (score 1):

The second for loop should be outside of the first one:

```
print("1ST INPUT")
num_array = list()
num = int(input("Enter how many elements you want: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    element = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array.append(element)

print("2nd input")
num_array2 = list()

for i in range(0, num): #I want to make the same size of element from the first one.
    element1 = float(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    num_array2.append(element1)

print(num_array)
print(num_array2)
```

Output:

```
% python a.py
1ST INPUT
Enter how many elements you want: 3
1. 12
2. 123
3. 1234
2nd input
1. 21
2. 321
3. 4321
[12.0, 123.0, 1234.0]
[21.0, 321.0, 4321.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
  #do stuff with first list

for i in range(0, n):
  #do stuff with second list
```

Don't use nested for loops in that case.
n is the same for both lists, so you don't have to use black magic to solve this.

```
num_array = []
```

You can create a list like this, its more readable than list() imo.